# How to truncate every float number in a file using sed, awk or something like it?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Let's say I have something like the following in a file:

```
ASD22
0.00133272
ASD23
0.00176711
ASD24
0.00175753
```

And I want to truncate every number (ignoring the rest) to get something like:

```
ASD22
0.0013
ASD23
0.0017
ASD24
0.0017
```

Keeping the "column look" to the output file.
Is there a easy and compact way to do it using something like sed or awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk can work:

```
awk '$1 == ($1+0) {$1 = sprintf("%0.4f", $1-0.00005)} 1' file
ASD22
0.0013
ASD23
0.0017
ASD24
0.0017
```

`$1-0.00005` is there to avoid rounding floating point number.

Comment: I like the way you check if it's a number. +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll be checking all of them tonight. Is $1+0 the part where you check if that's a number?

Comment: Yes that's right `$1 == ($1+0)` is a check to make sure we only operate on numbers.

Comment: Just another thing, if i'm not abusing you: How do I write if I want to make a loop for a lot of columns? I don't know how to, let's say, use a counter like "j" to iterate from 1 to 4 so I can do it from columns 1 to 4.

Comment: in `awk` to iterate from 1 to 4 columns use `{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}`

Comment: I could be wrong but I think this approach will give different results on different platforms. In many systems awk rounding is unbiased (i.e. rounds to even) which means that approach would convert `0.00130000` to `0.0012` rather than truncating it to `0.0013` since 0.00130000 - 0.00005 = 0.00125000 and then `sprintf("%0.4f"` would round that towards the even number `0.0012`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Round-Function.html

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for your helpful comment. I had verified on OSX and gnu awk and got `0.0013`. I will test it on Ubuntu and few Linux flavors today

Comment: FWIW I used a different approach a few mins ago at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53782092/1745001.

Answer (score 6):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\.[0-9]\{4\}\)[0-9]\{1,\}/\1/' YourFile
```

- truncate to 4 digit after the dot, if any
- look is preserved so if number is not starting with `0.` or a space is in front, it is unchanged for this part

Comment: +1 because this is a more generic solution to this problem which does not care where the number in the text resides

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cut -c1-6 file
ASD22
0.0013
ASD23
0.0017
ASD24
0.0017
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep`:

```
$ grep -Eo "^.{,6}" file.txt 
ASD22
0.0013
ASD23
0.0017
ASD24
0.0017
```