# truncate decimal places in column

Tags: awk

How to truncate decimal places in column?
I want to print first comlumn, the second column, which decimal places will be cut (not round) to 4 places a then a text. Thank you

Input file

```
56603.6153    2.212645
56603.6156    2.215645
56603.6158    2.210845
56603.6161    2.216175
56603.6166    2.204975
56603.6168    2.195275
56603.6171    2.219587
56603.6173    2.210778
56603.6176    2.199887
```

I tried  this

```
awk -F. '{print $1"."substr($1,5,4)"   " $2"."substr($2,1,4)}' file
```

the output was:

```
56278.8   5545   2.5545 
56278.8   5549   2.5549 
56278.8   5554   2.5554 
56278.8   5559   2.5559   
56278.8   5563   2.5563    
56278.8   5568   2.5568
```

I would like to get

```
56278.8554   2.5545   
56278.8555   2.5554    
56278.8555   2.5559     
56278.8556   2.5563    
56278.8556   2.5568
```

Comment: [MCVE](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) please

Comment: I am sorry I editted it. Is it MWC? I have file of numbers that I sent and I wrote to terminal linux what I sent before.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I added it in my question

Comment: Isn't your whole question really just about how to truncate $2 and all of the other fields in the input and output and printing 1s and 6s are just extraneous distractions that are cluttering up your question? If so - fix your question to get rid of all of that.

Comment: I am sorry, the question is ok now, I hope

Comment: The output numbers do not match the input numbers at all. Is there some unspecified transformation, or did you simply use unrelated input and output data? The expected output *for the example input* should be what's in the example.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not rounding?

Comment: Bacause the values would be not precise for some number of decimal places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that your expected output doesn't match your sample input means we can't adequately test a solution but maybe this is what you want:

```
$ awk '
    { print t($1), t($2) }
    function t(n,  s) { s=index(n,"."); return (s ? substr(n,1,s+4) : n) }
' file
56603.6153 2.2126
56603.6156 2.2156
56603.6158 2.2108
56603.6161 2.2161
56603.6166 2.2049
56603.6168 2.1952
56603.6171 2.2195
56603.6173 2.2107
56603.6176 2.1998
```

Wrap the return from t() in `sprintf("%.04f",...)` if you care about making all values that format rather than just truncating when necessary, i.e.:

```
function t(n,  s) { s=index(n,"."); return sprintf("%.04f",(s ? substr(n,1,s+4) : n)) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can I ask you to explan me this part? { s=index(n,"."); return (s ? substr(n,1,s+4) : n) }. What does (n,".") mean?

Comment: You're welcome. Did you try looking up any of that in the awk manual? Try googling `awk index` https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+index and click on the first result.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Also, there is always the multiply-by-10000-extract-the-integer-part-divide-by-10000-and-print-4-decimals way:</s>

```
$ awk '{printf "%s %0.4f\n", $1, int($2*10000)/10000}' file
56603.6153 2.2126
56603.6156 2.2156
56603.6158 2.2108
56603.6161 2.2161
56603.6166 2.2049
56603.6168 2.1952
56603.6171 2.2195
56603.6173 2.2107
56603.6176 2.1998
```

Just don't use it.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that won't introduce errors due to floating point arithmetic in the $2*10000 and then int() truncating the result towards zero and then a division by 10000 producing another float followed by sprintf() truncating towards even (or whatever direction the platform implements? I'd be wary...

Comment: It's past midnight over here, did you have a specific example in mind? I already turned off the left side of my brain...

Comment: Something like $2=2.212799999999999 ending up as 2.2128. idk if it'll be a problem or not I'm just suspicious of the floating point ops and the different roundings for int() and sprintf().

Comment: That probably wouldn't but I'm sure I'll dream of something devilish that'll wake me up 3 AM.

Comment: So, what am I seeing here: `awk 'BEGIN{a=1.634000;b=a*10000;print a,b,a*10000,int((a*10000)),int(b),int(a*10000)/10000}'` outputs `1.634 16340 16340 16339 16339 1.6339` that `int(b)==16339` especially.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{a=1.634000;b=int(a*10000);print a*10000,b,int(b)}'` outputs `16340 16339 16339`. Apparently `10000*1.634000 == 16339.9990` and what gets printed is not what it is in reality.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the scenario I had just figured out would be a problem if it could happen (but had also just talked myself out of thinking it could actually happening so that shows what I know!). It's the FP arithmetic on X*10000 coming up with an approximation that's 0.001 smaller than X, but that marginal reduction makes it 1 smaller in the first 5 digits and then int() rounds towards zero.

Comment: In case it helps, here's the comment I WAS going to leave: I've thought about this some more and I think the only way there could be a problem is if there was some value of $2 which when multiplied by 10000 ended up with a lower number in the last 5 digits than it started with, e.g. if 3.0000001 * 10000 somehow became 29999.999999 or similar as a result of that floating point arithmetic. Then int() would round towards zero and hilarity ensues. I don't THINK that could happen but idk, the intricacies of  FP arithmetic aren't really something I care to care about!